# Can't connect to godaddy MySQL with java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to connect to a mysql db, but I keep getting error:
**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

I know the url suppose to be: "jdbc:mysql://server-url:3306"

here is the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class FT_Database_Connection{
private Connection connection;

public FT_Database_Connection(String url, String username, String password){
    try{
        System.out.println("Loading driver...");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");

        String user = username;
        String db_pw = password;
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
        Connection test = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, db_pw);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't get database connection.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection get_connection(){
    return this.connection;
}

}
```

Any ideas?

Also, Godaddy ask if I want **DSN**. What's that mean? Do I need it?

Thanks

Comment: I can't look up GoDaddy at work, but somewhere in that URL string has to be something that identifies the MySQL database as your MySQL database.  server-url is too generic.

Comment: A lot depends on your GoDaddy configuration. Typically, they restrict connections to their database servers to their internal networks only. So if you're not running your Java code on a GoDaddy server, you may have issues connecting through their firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, GoDaddy has a couple of different MySQL DB implementations you can choose.  One that allows for remote access, and one that does not.  Are you sure that you have chosen the correct one?

Have you tried connecting remotely using MySQL Workbench first?  Or even telnetting to the port?  That will ensure you have the right db name and permissions to connect remotely.  Once you can confirm that works, getting the code to work should be easier.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your database name after the MySQL port (:3306/DB_name).  Here's one of my connections:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySQL{

    static Connection connect;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Credentials();

    Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/" + datab;

    Driver test = DriverManager.getDriver(url);
    // testing to make sure i'm using the correct
    //driver and further testing host
    System.out.println(test);
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

    System.out.println ("Connected to " + host);
    }
}
```

You'll need to supply the "host" and "datab" string values

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the DB name and not the table name?  Posting full (working) class file above...one sec

Comment: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/" + datab;` was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hate to add a new post to something so old but I ran across the same issues with GoDaddy and their dbname.db.######.hostedresource.com implementation. Granted, I looked across a few Overflow posts and saw no mention of the direct IP method; hopefully I'm not breaking some GoDaddy code here.

Any who, the only way I was able to connect through my Workbench & through JDBC was by going to the PHP admin page and grabbing the direct IP to the database - in my case :

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://11.11.111.11:3306/dbname";
```